# Delete File error

Tags: php, laravel, web

I am trying to delete a file after I delete the product from the database, but it shows me an error, and I cannot find a solution.

> Call to a member function delete() on null

```
public function supprod($id,Request $request)
{
    $produits=Produit::find($id);
    $produits->delete();  // <-- error on this line
    $filename=(string)$document->nom;
    Storage::disk('fichier')->delete($filename);
    return redirect()->back();
  }
```

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wit5A.png)

Comment: `find` can return `null` ... its very simple, there is no `Produit` with that `id` ... all in the docs

Comment: A product with the ID you're using does not exist. I would suggest using `findOrFail($id)` instead of `find($id)`, as this will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` resulting in a 404 to the user when a model isn't found.

Comment: it worked but the image still found in the storage folder while i am trying to delete it

Answer (score 0):

this is check the record this function `$produits=Produit::find($id);`
This use `$produits=Produit::where('id',$id)->first();`

Answer (score 0):

You should really let Laravel do the work for you.

Change your action to:

```
 public function supprod(Produit $id, Request $request) {
       $filename=(string)$id->nom;
       Storage::disk('fichier')->delete($filename);
       $id->delete();
       return redirect()->back();
 }
```

This will make the framework find the appropriate model or throw a 404 error if it does not exist.

More information in the [implicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#implicit-binding) section of the documentation

Comment: this didn't work and it show me that there is an error in this line



       Storage::disk('fichier')->delete($filename);




he didn't recognize the 'fichier'

Comment: I copied that from your code. I assume you've configured a disk called `fichier` ?

Comment: I didn't .. maybe this is my fault how do i correct it ! 
 i have just this line in my add product controller

       $url=Storage::url('$filename');
and not in the delete controller

Comment: `Storage::delete ($filename)` might be enough

Comment: it show me this error
Trying to get property of non-object

and it color this line
          $filename=(string)$id->nom;